# How can fopen_s be more safe than fopen?

Tags: c++, windows, msvcrt, crt, tr24731

I'm working on legacy code for `Windows` platform. When I compile the code in `VS2013`, it give following warning:

> error C4996: '`fopen`': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using `fopen_s` instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details."

And it will also give samiliar warning for `sprintf`. I understand `sprintf_s` is more safe than sprintf because of buffer overflow.

But how can be [fopen_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) be more safe than `fopen`, there is no chance of buffer overflow because `fopen` doesn't accept an buffer. Can anyone provide an case `fopen` is unsafe, and `fopen_s` is safe?

Comment: The documentation site you linked to has [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/8ef0s5kh(v=vs.90).aspx) on the very first page.

Comment: @H2CO3, I have checked this page, but it doesn't mension fopen and fopen_s

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `s` doesn't stand for "safe" in this case, it stands for "security enhanced". For `fopen_s`, the parameters are checked for validity before attempting to open the file.

With `fopen`, you can pass a NULL pointer for the filename and everything will most likely fall to pieces. `fopen_s` doesn't have that problem <sup>(a)</sup>.

Keep in mind that these bounds checking interfaces like `fopen_s` are an *optional* part of the ISO standard, detailed in Annex K (as at C11, anyway). Implementations are not *required* to provide them and, to be honest, `fopen`, and many other so-called unsafe functions, are perfectly safe if you know what you're doing as a coder.

It's interesting to note that `fopen_s` will trap NULL pointers for you but not invalid pointers, hence why it's security enhanced rather than safe - you can still cause some damage if you pass an invalid but non-NULL pointer.

Other "safe" functions which force you to provide destination buffer sizes are also safe only as long as you pass the right size. Pass something too big and all bets are off.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> From `C11 K.3.5.2.1 The fopen_s function`:

```
errno_t fopen_s (
    FILE * restrict * restrict streamptr,
    const char * restrict      filename,
    const char * restrict      mode);
```

> **Runtime-constraints**
>
> None of streamptr, filename, or mode shall be a null pointer.
>
> If there is a runtime-constraint violation, fopen_s does not attempt to open a file. Furthermore, if streamptr is not a null pointer, fopen_s sets *streamptr to the null pointer.

Contrast that with `C11 7.20.5.3 The fopen function` which states that the filename and mode must both point to a string but don't specify what happens if you provide a NULL pointer (most implementations would likely crash with a null pointer dereference).

Comment: When you say "fall to pieces" are you means fopen will crash, but fopen_s will return error?

Comment: @ZijingWu, yes, that's the most likely case. An implementation of `fopen` _could_ catch a NULL filename or mode, and return an error, but most will simply go off into la-la land as they attempt to dereference bad memory. Have updated the answer with more detail.

Comment: But why did Microsoft decide to take that much trouble of inventing a new function and deprecating the old one if they could have reached the same effect by adding the check for a NULL pointer to fopen, without any harm and much less trouble for everybody? If it's undefined by the standard, what keeps them from defining it for their implementation?

Comment: Note that the standard C library specifies in [C11 §7.1.4 Use of library functions](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.4): _Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an invalid value (such as …, or a pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or …, the behavior is undefined._  Thus, passing a null pointer to `fopen()` invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Note that the default behavior of the Microsoft C Run-Time Library's *Invalid Parameter Handler* will crash the program too, this time on purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Back when VS2005 came out I thought it was simply Microsoft going too far with their "let's make proprietary functions instead of giving people `snprintf()`", since both would (by default) raise a win32 exception if passed a NULL pointer (though `fopen` would raise `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION` whereas `fopen_s` would raise `STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER`). Which means both would result in the program crashing immediately unless Win32-specific code is added to handle the exception.

However, a peek in the CRT source code did reveal one small difference: The sharing flags used by `fopen` are fully permissive, whereas those used by `fopen_s` [forbid other processes from opening the file for writing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46268143/1455631). In that way, `fopen_s` is more secure since it means the file won't change under your process's feet.